# How to do the custom module enable/disable not working in admin - Magento

Tags: magento, module, admin

Initially I am newbie to magento. So please help me to learn magento. I have created a custom module named 'card voucher'. I need to enable or disable the module form adminpanel. So I created system.xml on

My app/code/community/card/voucher/etc/system.xml. The code is shown below

```
<config>
<tabs>
    <myconf translate="label">
        <label>card voucher</label>
        <sort_order>150</sort_order>
    </myconf>
</tabs>
<sections>
    <tab1 translate="label" module="adminhtml">
        <label>Enable / Disable</label>
        <tab>myconf</tab>
        <sort_order>10</sort_order>
        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
        <groups>
            <general translate="label comment">
                <label>General</label>
                <sort_order>50</sort_order>
                <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                <comment><![CDATA[This is a <strong>card voucher</strong> Extension used for checking voucher code.<br />You can simply enable disable this extension here. ]]></comment>
                <fields>

                    <active translate="label comment">
                        <label>Enable/Disable</label>
                        <frontend_type>select</frontend_type>
                        <sort_order>54</sort_order>
                        <source_model>adminhtml/system_config_source_enabledisable</source_model>
                        <show_in_default>1</show_in_default>
                        <show_in_website>1</show_in_website>
                        <show_in_store>1</show_in_store>
                    </active>
                </fields>
            </general>
        </groups>
    </tab1>
</sections>
```

Then I disabled the module but still live on my site. I think this code is only enough to establish this feature.

Please help me as soon as possible

Thanks

Comment: Disable module from app/etc/modules then clear cache and log out from admin. This should work after that.

Comment: Ok @ Chiragit007 , but that is a manual way, is there any possibility to do the enable/disable process via admin panel.

Comment: Yes go System -> Configuration -> Advanced section. Find your module over there and set it to "disable". Don't forget to save your settings at the end.

Comment: And flush cache to re-read `core_config_data` table so the setting will take.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally you would want to disable the module functionality and not the module itself from system config.

What exactly does this module do?

In you code

```
if(Mage::getStoreConfig('sectionName/groupName/active')){
  // run your code

}
```

Comment: Thanx @P.S, Initially the use of this module is to checking the status of voucher code( to know whether it is expired or not ). Then the given code where I need to paste on my module. Please tell more specifically. Thanks :)

Comment: @P.S, Indexcontroller.php?

Comment: can you add the code for your indexController.php. All you need to do is wrap the code around that if statement and decide what you want to show when the module is disable